# How to convert a UIColor to a black and white UIColor

Tags: swift

I am setting the background color of my label, but I would like to have the color be the black and white UIColor instead of the original UIColor.

```
self.MyLabel.backgroundColor = self.selectedColors.color
```

Comment: `self.myLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.black` doesn't work?

Comment: backgroundColor has to be UIColor so I get this error "Static member 'black' cannot be used on instance of type 'UIColor'"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like you'll need to convert your colour to grayscale.

While you can do this by averaging the R, G and B components of the colour, apple actually provide a nice [method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/1621927-getwhite) to grab the grayscale value:

```
func getWhite(_ white: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGFloat>?, 
    alpha: UnsafeMutablePointer<CGFloat>?) -> Bool
```

So to use this, you would first extract the grayscale colour and then init a new UIColor:

```
let originalColor = self.selectedColors.color

var white: CGFloat = 0
var alpha: CGFloat = 0
guard originalColor.getWhite(&white, alpha: &alpha) else {

    // The color couldn't be converted! Handle this unexpected error
    return
}

let newColor = UIColor(white: white, alpha: alpha)
self.MyLabel.backgroundColor = newColor
```

Answer (score 1):

By thanks of @Sam answer, I write an extension for `UIColor`:

```
extension UIColor {
    
    var grayScale: UIColor? {
        var white: CGFloat = 0
        var alpha: CGFloat = 0
        guard self.getWhite(&white, alpha: &alpha) else {
            return nil
        }
        return UIColor(white: white, alpha: alpha)
    }
}
```

You can use it like this:

```
var grayScaleColorOfRed = UIColor.red.grayScale ?? UIColor.grey
```